# PowerShell WindowStyle -Hidden working on Windows 10 but not Windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-5.0

I am making an application that uses the Start-Process cmdlet.

Start-Process with -WindowStyle Hidden (or Minimized and others) doesn't have an effect on this particular application link, Docker QuickStart Terminal on Windows 7. I am using Docker Toolbox instead of Docker for Windows.

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden -FilePath "$env:appdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Docker\Docker Quickstart Terminal.lnk"
```

It launches the application with no problem but it doesn't hide the application unlike on Windows 10. I am confused because normal shortcut links (Chrome and Internet Explorer) and other applications launches and hides/minimizes properly on both platforms. The only problem is with this particular shortcut link.

I am unsure if this is a problem that is associated with the PowerShell versions, 2.0 on Windows 7 and 5.0 on Windows 10.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docker shortcut starts bash.exe that starts another bash.exe that starts another bash.exe.
Bash is built-in in Windows 10, but not in previous versions of Windows, so I guess that's the reason.

Let's parse the shortcut file and manually launch its target:

```
function runProgramShortcutHidden($relativePath) {
    $programsMenu = [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Programs)
    $fullPath = Join-Path $programsMenu $relativePath

    $linkDir = (New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace((Split-Path $fullPath))
    $link = $linkDir.ParseName((Split-Path -leaf $fullPath)).GetLink

    $psi = New-Object Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $psi.FileName = $link.Path
    $psi.Arguments = $link.Arguments
    $psi.WorkingDirectory = $link.WorkingDirectory
    $psi.WindowStyle = [Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Hidden

    [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi) >$null
}
```

Usage:

```
runProgramShortcutHidden 'Docker\Docker Quickstart Terminal.lnk'
```

Notes:

- Unicode in shortcut's target path is supported since the code uses ShellLink interface;
- [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class is used in order to pass the argument string as is.

Comment: Hi, I missed out the fact that I'm using Docker Toolbox instead of Docker for Windows. I think Docker Toolbox uses the not built-in Git Bash. I will study more on PowerShell (I know very little) to understand what you just wrote before I come back to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, so it works fine on Windows 10 but not Windows 7, doesn't contain 'GetLink', http://imgur.com/a/xqOmn

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for responding, I can't verify the answer now as the  machine to test this is unavailable now. I will verify it tomorrow. One more question, can I add this line `$psi.ArgumentList = run.sh` if I want run.sh as the argument for ArgumentList?

Comment: Okay I realised that ^ doesn't work. I wanted to be able to specify `-ArgumentList run.sh` because I needed it to run a shell script and then exit on its own.

Comment: As a quoted string: `$psi.Arguments = 'param1 param2 "param in quotes"'` but do note, it replaces the entire argument string so you might want to add it to the existing one from the $link.

Comment: ProcessStartInfo doesn't have ArgumentList. I've used this class for the opposite purpose: to reuse the shortcut's arguments (which is a single string) directly.

Comment: The shorcut target looks like `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"` is this what's meant by argument string, if so how do I actually add it to the existing one from the $link. Sorry, I just started using PowerShell only to launch this link in the backgorund so I'm a bit clueless

Comment: Look up `bash` parameter syntax. Maybe you'll need to edit `start.sh` in a  text editor and add `run.sh` there. Or maybe you'll need to change the command line. Use google.